# switch search pattern in a line to titlecase leaving remainder of line unchanged

Tags: regex, vim, sed

I want to convert the UPPERCASE words in the following line:

```
<h3><a href="#ch15Toc" name="ch15Txt"></a>XV. THE THOUSAND AND ONE GOALS</h3>
```

to titlecase, using either sed or ved (vim ed). Googling turned up ways to Titlecase whole lines but not just text that matches a pattern search (partial text in a line)

thought this might work, but no dice:

```
sed -ri '/<h3>/s/([A-Z ]*)<\/h3>/\L\1\END<\/h3>/;s/[[:graph:]]*/\u&/g'
```

after converting the search pattern to LOWERCASE (no probs of course managing that), I thought I might be able to then convert same text to Titlecase with something like this, but still no love (I actually thought this made enough sense to work, so I am unsure why it doesn't):

```
sed -ri 's/(<\/a>[IVX]{1,6}\.[ ]{1,})( [a-z])/\1\u\2/g'
```

Is there some way to edit only the text in a pattern search to Titlecase and not all the words in an entire line of text? I wonder why there is not a \T to compliment the \L and \u case commands. Sure would be handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%s/\v<\zs(\u)(\u*)\ze>/\1\L\2/g
```

in vim, after you executed this command, your line will be turned into:

```
<h3><a href="#ch15Toc" name="ch15Txt"></a>Xv. The Thousand And One Goals</h3>
```

vim has `substitute()` and other powerful functions, which are very handy to do substitution on matched text, if your requirement is complex enough.   `:s/.../\=(expression here)/`

only do replacement in `<h3>....</h3>`:

```
%s#<h3>\zs.*\ze</h3>#\=substitute(submatch(0), '\v<\zs(\u)(\u*)\ze>','\1\L\2',"g")#
```

Comment: that worked, and it was easy enough to re-convert the roman nums. to UPPERCASE afterward. I will hafta check out those ved options with which I am totally unfamiliar.

Comment: actually I was a bit quick. This command also changes case of UPPERCASE words on lines that do not have an <h3> tag in its line, which is why I made that a delimiter for my first sed try and included a closing anchor tag <\/a> in the second sed search pattern to ensure only lines with either-or would be affected. Is there a quick mod to your command to limit the search pat to lines with either <h3> or <\/a> tag?

Comment: @nanker you can first get the things between `<h3> and </h3>` and apply the same pattern on that, shall I provide a new command for that or you will try first by yourself? `:h s/\=` may help.

Comment: @nanker I added in answer.